# What does "collect all mutually $R$-equivalnent elements in $A$" mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

I am reading "Sets, Numbers and Topology" by Masahiko Saito.

> Let $R$ be an equivalence relation on a set $A$.
>   If we collect all mutually $R$-equivalnent elements in $A$, we get a subset of $A$.
>   Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of all such subsets of $A$.
>   Then, $\mathcal{F}$ is a classification of $A$.
>   An element of $\mathcal{F}$ is called an equivalence class with respect to $R$.

What does "***collect all mutually $R$-equivalnent elements in*** $A$" mean?
I cannot understand this operation exactly.

Comment: Do you know the definition of equivalence relation?  Then what the author means (he is not clear) is we pick an element $a\in A$.  The subset of $R$-equivalent elements of $a$ is $\{ x\in A \,\, | \,\, xRa \}$

Comment: @NazimJ Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase *all mutually $R$-equivalent elements* is misleading. It's like specifying "all integers which end with the same digit"—which is obviously only defined once we choose the digit.

What it's really saying is this.

**Choose some element $a$ of $A$.**  (Crucial but not mentioned.) Then $R$ defines a subset $S\subset A$ each of whose elements is equivalent to $a$: that is, every $x\in S$ satisfies $xRa$.

The **mutually equivalent** part is that for any $x, y\in S$, each of $x$ and $y$ is equivalent to the other: $xRy$ and $yRx$. **Every element of $S$ is equivalent, under $R$, to every other.**

This follows from the definition of an equivalence relation, by which $R$ is both transitive (if $aRbRc$ then $aRc$) and commutative (if $aRb$ then $bRa$).

The book goes on to say that $S$ is called an equivalence class, and that the set of equivalence classes is called a classification.

Comment: Thank you very much, timtfj.